# karma test pass but npm test give error

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, angular, npm, karma-runner

i use https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter and have foloowing problem: when I'm in project directory and run

```
karma start
```

Then i get:

> SUMMARY:
>
> ✔ 0 tests completed

But when i run:

```
npm test
```

I get:

> SUMMARY:
>
> ✔ 0 tests completed
>
> npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

If I run:

```
npm run test
```

I get:

```
SUMMARY:
✔ 0 tests completed

npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.1.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "test"
npm ERR! node v7.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-webpack-starter@5.0.5 test: `karma start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-webpack-starter@5.0.5 test script 'karma start'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-webpack-starter package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     karma start
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-webpack-starter
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-webpack-starter
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Kamil/Desktop/Code/officewise/officewise_frontend/npm-debug.log
```

Any idea what to do to remove this npm ERR? This is important for me because I use some external system to run tests and report errors of new commits in repository (my node version v7.1.0 (lastest), npm version 4.0.2 (lastest), Mac OS Sierra).

Comment: Do you have the same version of `karma` installed locally and globally?

Comment: Version is the same global and local: Karma version: 0.13.22

Comment: Have you tried removing `node_modules`, running `npm cache clear`, followed by `npm install`?

Comment: I try this - steel the same error... :(

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski This is a long shot, but do you remember if you solved the error? If so, do you remember what you did? Thanks!

Comment: @Guillaume as I remember I not found solution. Do you use that old angular-starter  version or error occure also in fresh new version of https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter ? If in new version too you can try to create ISSUE on that github repo.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski I found the solution. I will write an answer to your post to help anyone who might have this problem in the future

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Karma exits with an  error if there are no tests to run.

To disable this behaviour, you need to add this line to your Karma configuration:

```
failOnEmptyTestSuite: false
```